# Vote Count Viewer

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, userscript

I've written a small script to enable the vote count viewing functionality that comes for users at 1k reputation:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Vote count viewer
// @namespace   https://github.com/The-Quill/VoteCountViewer
// @version     1.0
// @description Lets you view the vote count on posts.
// @author      Quill
// @match *://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match *://meta.*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match *://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match *://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match *://serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match *://meta.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match *://superuser.com/questions/*
// @match *://meta.superuser.com/questions/*
// @match *://askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match *://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('vote-count-post')).forEach(function(post) {
        post.addEventListener("click", getScore);
    });
    function getScore() {
        var post = this;
        var postId = post.parentElement.children[0].value;
        var site = document.location.hostname;
        var url = "//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/" + postId + "?site=" + site + "&key=fetJx5PJVUspEFsbpN9n1A((&filter=!.UE7HKkP*tRsqwc8";
        var ups = 0;
        var downs = 0;
        $.getJSON(url, function(e) {
            ups = parseInt(e.items[0].up_vote_count, 10);
            downs = parseInt(e.items[0].down_vote_count, 10);
        }).done(function() {
            post.title = ups + " up / " + downs + " down";
            post.innerHTML = "";
            var green = document.createElement('div');
            green.style.color = "green";
            green.textContent = ups;
            var separator = document.createElement('div');
            separator.classList.add('vote-count-separator');
            var maroon = document.createElement('div');
            maroon.color = "maroon";
            maroon.textContent = downs;

            post.appendChild(green);
            post.appendChild(separator);
            post.appendChild(maroon);
        });
    };
})();
```

Comment: I'm confused. Does this UserScript add the functionality for users who don't already have it?

Comment: Yes @SirPython, it does.

Answer (score 6):

You'd probably be better off renaming your `var green` and `var maroon` to something like `var upElement` and `var downElement`. The reason being if you later decide to use different colors you wouldn't need to change the variable name to match the new colors.

Instead of `parseInt` you can use `+` i.e `ups = +e.items[0].up_vote_count;`

If you're concerned about performance, you could create a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) to which you would append your `green, separator, maroon` elements, before appending the fragment to `post`.

If you don't need to support IE you could use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch) instead of relying on jQuery's `getJSON`, :

```
var getCounts = function (e) {
  return {
    ups : parseInt(e.items[0].up_vote_count, 10),
    downs = parseInt(e.items[0].down_vote_count, 10)
  }
}

var showCounts = function (counts) {
    var ups = counts.ups;
    var downs = counts.downs;
    // etc;
}

fetch(url).then(getCounts).then(showCounts)
```

Comment: I disagree with using `+` instead of `parseInt`; that is very "hacky" and should only be reserved for golfing.

Comment: @SirPython - `+` behaves differently to `parseInt` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which .

Comment: That's a very interesting post; thanks for sharing! However, I still believe it's a bit hacky. Perhaps `Number()` could be used instead, as they will both generate the same value?